# What is the proper way of including a PHP variable in HTML?

Tags: php, html

I want to include variable `$var` from this `file.php`:

```
<?php

  $var = 5;

?>
```

into this `php` file with `html` code:

```
<?php include "file.php" ?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Include this variable: <?php echo $var ?></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image]

This seems to work but PhpStorm shows an error at `$var` inside the `html`:

```
Undefined variable '$var'
```

Is this a bad practice or a PhpStorm problem? How to do it right?

Comment: It looks like phpstorm does not see the included file, but your code works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that file.php is included in your project.
Also you can update the inspection settings and enable: "Search for variable's definition outside the current file"

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: The proposed setting fixed the error msg for me. Thanks!